# Failed to start nfs-server.service:Transaction order is cyclic

Tags: centos, nfs

OS: CentOS 7.5 1804

```
systemctl enable rpcbind
systemctl enable nfs

# /etc/exports

/mnt/FileServer *(insecure,rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

nfs not start at boot, and failed when start manually.

```
systemd[1]:Found ordering cycle on nfs-server.service/start
systemd[1]:Found dependency on mnt-FileServer.mount/start
systemd[1]:Found dependency on nfs-server.service/start
systemd[1]:Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job mnt-FileServer.mount/start
```

Found same issue at https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Cloud/2649787_1.html

but don't have oracle support account.

Comment: Seems to be [a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1471922) (and not only in Centos, it would seem from the number of documents found by searching for *nfs "Found Ordering cycle"*. Solution is probably to update to a later Centos version.

Comment: @berndbausch thanks for the comment.Maybe update to a later Centos version can avoid this issue, but I'm searching for solution to fix this issue at current set up.I want to know what caused this, because it was not goes wrong at before time.

Comment: Can you start the service by hand. systemctl start nfs then do systemctl status?

Comment: @MarkScheck systemctl start nfs failed and show those 'Found ordering cycle ' text.After remove nfs and rpcbind, reboot, reinstall nfs and rpcbind, systemctl status last line change to 'Unable to break cycle'

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I see various flavors of this issue reported in several places. For me, the key was https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183999 or more specifically, adding `DefaultDependencies=False` to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-client.target`

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue on RHEL 8.4.

For me commenting the entry in `/etc/exports` and doing

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start nfs-server
```

did the trick.

NFS services started successfully, and then I was able to add the entry again on `/etc/exports` and restarted `nfs-server`.

But once I reboot the VM, it's the same issue again!!